# iphone - Can't uninstall app on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am testing my app on my jailbreaked iPhone and i noticed something strange.

When i want to uninstall it on device i got no cross to delete the app. All the other apps (not mines) have the white circled cross.
Whereas on the simulator i am able to delete my app.

Is it because i run it on a jailbreak with a codesign workaround?

Or maybe i am missing something in the app plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't written any app with a codesign workaround, since I have valid license, but it makes sense that you can't delete it on the fly. None of the Cydia installed apps have a white cross to delete. 
Maybe you can try CyDelete this enables to delete Cydia apps from your home screen. Or look into your Cydia packages list if it's in there

Comment: hi hecta,

indeed i found my app in Cydia/packages.

thx for the answer mate

Wallou
Bye